# Check if a specific certificate is installed on a device

Tags: android, certificate

Is there a possibility to check if a specific certificate is installed on an Android Device? For example a special company certificate?

Comment: ok after some more research it seems to be not possible. it should be possible with Android 4.0 ICS, but not with a lower version :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work on a device with Android `5.1.1`.

Depending how you want to check if it is the certificate that you are looking for, you can choose any field and compare it. I went for the quick way of just checking the issuer distinguished name (DN).

```
private boolean isCertificateInstalled(String issuerDn) {
    try {
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init((KeyStore) null);
        X509TrustManager xtm = (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
        for (X509Certificate cert : xtm.getAcceptedIssuers()) {
            if (cert.getIssuerDN().getName().contains(issuerDn)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
        // Handle exceptions
    }
    return false;
}
```

I took this solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32499836/3918479) that claims this should work also on pre IceCream Sandwich.