# Detect installed certificate in my android device

Tags: android, certificate

I am installing a certificate in my application when application starts. I have gone through few of the links as below and successfully install the certificate.

- http://nelenkov.blogspot.in/2011/12/ics-trust-store-implementation.html
- http://pastebin.com/Bn6qSYHx
- [How to programmatically install a CA Certificate (for EAP WiFi configuration) in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024721/how-to-programmatically-install-a-ca-certificate-for-eap-wifi-configuration-in)
- [how to install CA certificate programmatically on Android without user interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657172/how-to-install-ca-certificate-programmatically-on-android-without-user-interacti)

I came to know we cannot install the certificate silently without user interaction.Currently I don't know how to stop prompt each time user open my app.

Whenever my application starts currently every time it ask user to install certificate. Is there some way I can detect whether a certificate(in this case my certificate) is already installed or not, programmatically.

Code snippet where I have installing certificate in my app

```
private void installCertificate()
    {
        try 
        {
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(getAssets().open(MY_CERT));
            byte[] keychain = new byte[bis.available()];
            bis.read(keychain);

            Intent installIntent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
            X509Certificate x509 = X509Certificate.getInstance(keychain);
            installIntent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_CERTIFICATE, x509.getEncoded());
            installIntent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME, MY_CERT);
            startActivityForResult(installIntent, INSTALL_KEYCHAIN_CODE);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (CertificateException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        if (requestCode == INSTALL_KEYCHAIN_CODE) 
        {
            switch (resultCode) 
            {  
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    doTheTask();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    finish();
                    break;                  
                default:
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Also FYI, installCertificate() is called from onCreate().

Please help me out for the same. Any help will appreciated.

---

**Query:** When prompt comes for certificate name, entered text comes as selected and on orientation change cut/copy option comes. Any body knows how to stop text selection when prompt comes?!!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I used the below piece of Java code to check whether or not my certificate is installed:

```
try
{
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
    if (ks != null) 
    {
        ks.load(null, null);
        Enumeration aliases = ks.aliases();
        while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) 
        {
            String alias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate cert = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);

            if (cert.getIssuerDN().getName().contains("MyCert")) 
            {
                isCertExist = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (KeyStoreException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (java.security.cert.CertificateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I am using your code ,what should i use in place of  AndroidCAStore ?

Answer (score 4):

Adding some additional info to @Android's answer (I cannot comment yet), whose code worked for me only in devices with Android 4.0 or higher.

**For devices pre IceCream Sandwich (API < 14):**

```
boolean isCertExist;
    TrustManagerFactory tmf;
    try {
        tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory
                .getDefaultAlgorithm());

        tmf.init((KeyStore) null);

        X509TrustManager xtm = (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
        for (X509Certificate cert : xtm.getAcceptedIssuers()) {
            if (cert.getIssuerDN().getName().contains("MyCert")) {
                isCertExist = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**For devices with Android 4.0 and upwards (API >= 14):**

```
boolean isCertExist;
    try 
    {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
        if (ks != null) 
        {
            ks.load(null, null);
            Enumeration aliases = ks.aliases();
            while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) 
            {
                String alias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate cert = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);

                if (cert.getIssuerDN().getName().contains("MyCert")) {
                    isCertExist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.security.cert.CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Using this method I correctly get the certificate from the KeyStore, even if the user haven't yet typed password and certificate name in the modals opened by the Intent KeyStore.createInstallIntent()

Answer (score 1):

KeyChain.createInstallIntent, the created intent will call android.security.certinstaller to install certificates, then the certinstaller will print log when certificates are installed. so you can dump the log cat to check whether certificate is installed or not.(you can get the alias if user changed the store name of certificate)

Answer (score 1):

This is the Kotlin version of how to list all user-installed CA certificates on an Android device.
If you change **"user"** to **"system"** you'll get the pre-installed CA certificates instead. If you don't want this distinction you can remove the filter.

```
val userInstalledCaCertificates: List<X509Certificate> = try {
  val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore")
  keyStore.load(null, null)
  val aliasList = keyStore.aliases().toList().filter { it.startsWith("user") }
  aliasList.map { keyStore.getCertificate(it) as X509Certificate }
} catch (e: Exception) {
  emptyList()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading off from trusted CA store as below

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
```

will only fetch the CA certificates and not the user/client certificates. It is not necessary that client certificate share the same alias as that of the CA certificate.