# List of trusted CA certificates programmatically in Android

Tags: android, security, ca

I know the user can view the trusted CA certificates installed on the device looking into: settings > security > trusted CA certificates.
Do you if (and how) from inside my application I can get the list of CA certificates installed by the user?

Comment: Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: any lead on this ?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14979026/4254527